# CodeIgniter : Get value from single column from table

Tags: sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a table that contains personal data, such as name, gender, address, etc. my question is, how to get the total number of men and women from my table?

This is my SQL query :

```sql
SELECT gender, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM personaldata
GROUP BY gender
```

This is my code so far in my model :

```php
public function gender_count()
{
    $this->db->select('gender, count(*) as total');
    $this->db->from('personaldata');
    $this->db->group_by('gender');

    $query = $this->db->get()->row()->total;
    return $query->result();
}
```

So how to write that SQL query to CI model and controller? I just want to show the total gender in my site.

Thank you

Comment: Try two different queries for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are two ways to do that, you can choose which one you feel ease

Model:

```
public function gender_count()
{
    $response = array();
//for female
    $this->db->select('count(id) as ftotal');//id should be primary key
    $this->db->from('personaldata');
    $this->db->where('gender','f');
    $this->db->group_by('gender');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $response['f'] = $query->row('ftotal');
    }else{
        $response['f'] = 0;
    }
//for male
    $this->db->select('count(id) as mtotal');//id should be primary key
    $this->db->from('personaldata');
    $this->db->where('gender','m');
    $this->db->group_by('gender');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $response['m'] = $query->row('mtotal');
    }else{
        $response['m'] = 0;
    }
    return $response;//assosiative array
}
```

OR

```
public function gender_count()
{
    $response = array();
    $this->db->select('gender,count(id) as total');//id should be primary key
    $this->db->from('personaldata');
    $this->db->group_by('gender');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
          $response[$row->gender] = $row->total;
        }
    }else{
        $response['f'] = 0;
        $response['m'] = 0;
    }
    return $response;//assosiative array
}
```

Controller:

```
$data = array();
$genderCount = $this->Gender_model->gender_count();
$data['fcount'] = $genderCount['f'];
$data['mcount'] = $genderCount['m'];
$this->load->view('genderCount',$data);
```

View:

```
<span>Female:</span><b><?php echo $fcount;?></b>
<span>Male:</span><b><?php echo $mcount;?></b>
```

Comment: I got error says : Message: Undefined index: f and Message: Undefined index: m in my controller

Comment: in a model or in the controller ? can you share your `personaldata` table? I want to see your `gender` field

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, there is typo in my code :)
Now it work, big thanks buddy..

could you explain this code :

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
          $response[$row->gender] = $row->total;
        }

Comment: ya sure, if your `$query` have num_rows > 0 then only make your $respose array it means you have records or you have specific records

Answer (score 0):

Your can get total gender value by Count(*) and send that value from @OutputValue

```
Declare  @OutputValue int
select @OutputValue=COUNT(*) from personaldata
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function in your model and call it from controller.

> Model

```
public function gender_count()
{
    $this->db->select('gender, COUNT(*) as total');
    $this->db->group_by('gender'); 
    $query = $this->db->get('users', 10)->result();

    return $query;
}
```

> Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('User');

    $result = $this->User->gender_count();

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    die;
}
```

**Note :** I use my model name and table name as example so you need to use your model name and table name.

I hope this will work for you.